# Как оставить в массиве необходимые данные? php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно будет оставить в массиве необходимые данные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по ключам с 20 по 35

Comment: for ($tr=25; $tr<=35; $tr++){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `array_filter` позволит отфильтровать данные по значению. Можно пройтись по всем значениям и оставить только те, которые начинаются с `2019`:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($var){
    return substr($var, 0, 4) === '2019';
});
```

Где `$array` - изначальный массив.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=array('1'=>'2019-04-12','2'=>'2019-04-15','3'=>'2019-04-17','4'=>'2019-04-18','5'=>'2019-04-19','6'=>'2019-04-20','7'=>'2019-04-21','8'=>'2019-04-22','9'=>'2019-04-23','10'=>'2019-04-24','11'=>'2019-04-25','12'=>'2019-04-26','13'=>'2019-04-27','14'=>'2019-04-28','15'=>'2019-04-29','16'=>'2019-04-30','17'=>'2019-05-1','18'=>'2019-05-2','19'=>'2019-05-4','20'=>'2019-05-05','21'=>'2019-05-06','22'=>'2019-05-08','23'=>'2019-05-10','24'=>'2019-05-12','25'=>'2019-05-20','26'=>'2019-05-25');


for ($tr=13; $tr<=21; $tr++){

$new[$tr]=$arr[$tr];

}

print_r($new);
```